# How to detect that an item in a QStandardItemModel is dropped onto another?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I receive notification that a [QStandardItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditem.html) is dragged and then dropped onto another QStandardItem, thus becoming a child of the latter?

I thought I could do this by re-implementing [QStandardItemModel.moveRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#moveRows), but it is not getting called after a drop :( Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. To test, run the program and drop one item in the tree view onto another. If it worked, you should see confirmation in the console that `moveRows` has been called.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Model(QStandardItemModel):
    def moveRows(
            self, source_parent, source_row, count, destination_parent,
            destination_child):
        print(
            'Moving {} row(s) from row {} of parent {} to row {} of parent {}'
            .format(
                count, source_row, source_parent, destination_child,
                destination_parent)
        )
        super().moveRows(
            source_parent, source_row, count, destination_parent,
            destination_child)
        return True


def _create_item(text):
    item = QStandardItem(text)
    flags = Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
    item.setFlags(flags)
    return item


model = Model()
model.appendRow([_create_item('Item 1')])
model.appendRow([_create_item('Item 2')])

app = QApplication([])
view = QTreeView()
view.setDragDropMode(view.InternalMove)
view.setModel(model)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From studying the QStandardItemModel source code, I realized that one has to override [QAbstractItemModel.dropMimeData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dropMimeData), in order to react to item drops. QStandardItemModel moves items around in its implementation of `dropMimeData`, but in a way that a subclass can't hook into, so you have to handle `dropMimeData` yourself.

This is my `dropMimeData` based solution, item representations are included with MIME data as Python pickles:

```
import pickle
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


_mimeType = 'application/x-standarditemmodeldatalist'


class Model(QStandardItemModel):
    def dropMimeData(
            self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        # Access parent before calling super implementation, because it may mutate parent
        dest_str = 'parent {}'.format(parent.data(Qt.DisplayRole)) if \
            parent.isValid() else 'root'

        ret_val = super().dropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent)
        if action != Qt.MoveAction or not data.hasFormat(_mimeType):
            return ret_val

        item_data = pickle.loads(data.data(_mimeType))[0]
        print('Moving {} to {}'.format(item_data, dest_str))
        return True

    # Override in order to add custom MIME data
    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mimeData = super().mimeData(indexes)
        data = [index.data(Qt.DisplayRole) for index in indexes]
        mimeData.setData(_mimeType, pickle.dumps(data))

        return mimeData

    # Override in order to announce our custom MIME type
    def mimeTypes(self):
        return super().mimeTypes() + [_mimeType]


def _create_item(text):
    item = QStandardItem(text)
    flags = Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
    item.setFlags(flags)
    return item


model = Model()
model.appendRow([_create_item('Item 1')])
model.appendRow([_create_item('Item 2')])

app = QApplication([])
view = QTreeView()
view.setDragDropMode(view.InternalMove)
view.setModel(model)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```